# Provide a pre-saved wifi SSID and password when building AOSP

Tags: wifi, android-source, android-wifi

I there a way in android to provide some SSID name and passwords, so the device will connect automatically when building AOSP?

So this way we can put aside a tedious job as entering wifi pass wach time I burn the ROM into device!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a way to do this, but I can think of a workaround.
You can call the code to save SSID from the Provision app, which is run only once during first boot.

Or add that code in the WifiService, somewhere in this method: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiServiceImpl.java#505